# How to get the nearest documents for a word in gensim in python

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I am using the doc2vec model as follows to construct my document vectors.

```
from gensim.models import doc2vec
from collections import namedtuple

dataset = json.load(open(input_file))

docs = []
analyzedDocument = namedtuple('AnalyzedDocument', 'words tags')

for description in dataset:
    tags = [description[0]]
    words = description[1]
    docs.append(analyzedDocument(words, tags))

model = doc2vec.Doc2Vec(docs, vector_size = 100, window = 10, min_count = 1, workers = 4, epochs = 20)
```

I have seen that **gensim doc2vec also includes word vectors**. Suppose I have a word vector created for the word `deep learning`. My question is; is it possible to get the `documents` nearest to `deep learning` word vector in gensim in python?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: yes it is possible as this works on word analogies

Comment: @AnkushRasgon  how can we do it if it is possible? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some `Doc2Vec` modes will co-train doc-vectors and word-vectors in the "same space". Then, if you have a word-vector for `'deep_learning'`, you can ask for documents near that vector, and the results may be useful for you. For example:

```
similar_docs = d2v_model.docvecs.most_similar(
                   positive=[d2v_model.wv['deep_learning']]
               )
```

But:

- that's only going to be as good as your model learned `'deep_learning'` as a word to mean what you think of it as
- a training set of known-good documents fitting the category `'deep_learning'` (and other categories) could be better - whether you hand-curate those, or try to bootstrap from other sources (like say the Wikipedia category '[Deep Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Deep_learning)' or other curated/search-result sets that you trust).
- reducing a category to a single summary point (one vector) may not be as good as having a variety of examples – many points - that all fit the category. (Relevant docs may not be a neat sphere around a summary point, but rather populate exotically-shaped regions of the doc-vector high-dimensional space.) If you have a lot of good examples of each category, you could train a classifier to then label, or rank-in-relation-to-trained-categories, any further uncategorized docs.